# How to convert lambda syntax to regular syntax?

Tags: c#, lambda

I see a lot of questions about how to convert TO lambda syntax and very few of the opposite.

I don't speak C#, could anyone please help me dissect this:

```
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, (s, e) => {Debug.WriteLine("Xml schema validation error : " + e.Message);});
```

How will this line look without using lambda expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a method whose signature matches that of a `ValidationEventHandler` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.validationeventhandle)  and then pass the name of that function as the second parameter to `XmlSchema.Read`.  Something like `public void MyValidationEventHandler(object s, ValidationEventArgs e); { Debug.WriteLine("Xml schema validation error : " + e.Message); }` and then `XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, MyValidationEventHandler);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to translate it back into old-fashioned, pre-`=>` C#, you'd do something like:

```
private void OnValidationError(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($@"Xml schema validation error : {args.Message}");
}
```

and then call the Read method this way:

```
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, OnValidationError);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to write a local function:

```cs
void Error (object s, ValidationEventArgs e) => Debug.WriteLine("Xml schema validation error : " + e.Message);

XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, Error);
```

Comment: I am not looking for a "best way" as I know lambda expression is used for simplicity, however this simplicity comes at a cost of obscurity. Also it seems in your solution you also use lambda, the very thing I want to completely remove from my code.

Comment: @zooid It's an expression bodied method, add brackets if you like that sort of thing